# how to use if else condition in mysql query if attribute is a boolean datatype

Tags: mysql

```
 var sql = 'SELECT user_groups.*, groups.grp_display_name, user_groups.uug_active ' +' FROM user_groups, groups' +' WHERE user_groups.uug_is_deleted = 0 AND user_groups.group_id = groups.id  AND user_id ='+ userId + '\n';
```

in my database uug_active is 1 or 0.i want to use if_else condtion,so that if its 1 its will search for yes in my seachbox

Comment: if search box value is yes.. then you want to add `uug_active` is 1 otherwise 0 in where condition

Comment: no. actually in my database i have uug_active as 1 or 0........but in my frontend i want to search with 'yes' if it is 1 and NO if it is 0

Comment: So in your front end if you type 'yes' then the fetch results which are having `uug_active` is 1.. right?

Comment: yes ............you are right

Comment: try below code ..mostly it will works

Comment: is it if condition working?

Comment: if (body.search.value !== null & body.search.value !== '' ){
            where = " AND  (uug_group_id             LIKE "      + Query.escapeVal('%'+Query.escape(body.search.value)+'%') +
                    " OR   uug_active                LIKE "      + Query.escapeVal('%'+Query.escape(body.search.value)+'%') +
                    " OR   groups.grp_display_name   LIKE "      + Query.escapeVal('%'+Query.escape(body.search.value)+'%')+")";
                    
            sql += where;
        }

Comment: actually here i am using search conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT user_groups.*, groups.grp_display_name, user_groups.uug_active 
FROM user_groups, groups 
WHERE user_groups.uug_is_deleted = 0 AND user_groups.group_id = groups.id AND user_id ='+ userId+'
AND IF("'+ active_mode+'" = "yes", (user_groups.uug_active = 1), (user_groups.uug_active = 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please learn proper explicit `join` syntax and the use of table aliases:

```
SELECT ug.*, g.grp_display_name, g.uug_active 
FROM user_groups ug JOIN
     groups g
     ON ug.group_id = g.group_id
WHERE ug.uug_is_deleted = 0 AND user_id = $userId AND
      (uug_active <> 1 OR $searchbox = 'yes');
```

Note: you are embedding string data directly in the query.  You should be using parameterized queries, but this answer only addresses the logic in the database, not the application logic for calling the query.